# What can damage energy?

Tags: anima-beyond-fantasy

In Anima Beyond Fantasy the Nephilim Ebudan has an advantage called "Celestial Essence". It says that the Ebudan cannot be damaged by natural attacks that cannot damage energy. But, what exactly can damage energy? I haven't found the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ability to damage energy is something that needs to specifically be gained through some supernatural ability or item.

Here are some common examples of means to damage or affect energy:

- Ki Abilites:

  - Presence Extrusion - allows one to physically touch energy (core book pg.96)
  - Aura Extension - as above but extends to weapons or objects in hand (core book pg.96)
- Magic:

  - Any Spell with the "Type of Spell" listed as Spiritual
  - Any Spell that uses the Energy AT, ie. Magic Beam (core book pg. 167)
  - The Enchant spell (core 165) allows you to enchant an object, weapon or place to affect energy
- Psychic Abilities:

  - Any Power that checks against PsR

The following points utilize secondary books:

- Ki (Dominus Exxet secondary book)

  - Energy Damaging Attack Effect - when added to a technique, allows its other effects to affect energy (only required if aura extension is not obtained) (Dominus Exxet pg. 61)
  - Kiai Minor Ars Magnus - allows one to gain the effects of the Presence Extrusion Ki Ability for one turn (Dominus Exxet pg. 84)
  - Emptiness Extrusion Nemesis Ability - Allows one to attack on the Energy AT to deal cold damage (Dominus Exxet pg. 25)
- Magic (Arcana Exxet secondary book)

  - Metamagic node: Energy Control - allows spells that would not usually affect energy to do so, ie. Air Cut or Earth Spike (Arcana Exxet pg. 27)
- Items (Promethium Exxet secondary book)

  - Enchanted Weapon power - enchants the weapon to be capable of damaging energy (Promethium Exxet pg. 19)
  - Elemental Attacks power - if the Energy element is chosen for the weapon then it can damage energy (Promethium Exxet pg. 19)

In general if something utilizes the Energy AT, or calls for a Magic or Psychic resistance check (possibly also poison or disease depending on situation) then it can affect energy.

As a side note the Celestial Essence trait is only obtained upon completion of the task established as part of the Or'inie trait, not an innate ability (unless agreed upon with GM that part of the character's backstory was completing it, usually for higher level characters)